# Azure webapp and and their webjobs deployment

Tags: azure-devops, environment-variables, devops, azure-webjobs

I want to deploy webapp and their webjobs in environments using VSTS ci/cd.
Note:
1.The webapp having three webjobs( WJ1+ (WJ2+Its instance(2))
2.The webapp having 6 webjobs( WJ1+ (WJ2+Its instance(5)).
3.its not picking the variables which we aren't adding in release pipeline.

Quick help much appreciated
Thanks,
SP

Comment: What do you mean by 3 is not picking the variables from release pipeline? 
Web Job has nothing to do with the variables in release pipelein, if there is a settings you have to pass to your web job, you can do that from the Azure AppSettings section

Comment: There are so many variables that too passing  in every environment is tough right?

Comment: If each environment is deployed to a different web app, then you can set it in the appsettings section for each app. Another option is to use a task in the release pipeline that update the web.config or appsettings.json from the release pipeline variables

Comment: Shaddad,  could please provide steps how to do that which task I need to add.im new to CI/CD

Comment: I have added the links in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Web Jobs will not pick the variables from your release pipeline, instead it can get these variables/settings from the web app's appsettings section.

You can do that manually by setting the appsettings for the web app in Azure Portal by following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure

Or you can do it automatically by changing web.config/appsettings using transformation tasks in your release pipeline as instructed in this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops

As for the web jobs deployment:
If you added the web jobs from visual studio, it will add a file under the properties folder in your web app called webjobs-list.json. If it is not there, then add it and the content should be similar to:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjobs-list.json",
  "WebJobs": [
    {
      "filePath": "../webjob1.csproj"
    },
    {
      "filePath": "../webjob2.csproj"
    },
    {
      "filePath": "../webjob3.csproj"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much shaddad. What about the first two points? Any help

Comment: I have modified the answer to include the web job deployment as well

Comment: Instead adding in the code can we do any archive task